# Using Results from LINQ Join within Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a join query written in LINQ that joins two tables.

However, I'm struggling with accessing the attributes from both tables because I am using the primary table as the repeater's 'ItemType' declaration and it's not showing the newly joined columns for selection.

I feel that it's because I need to create an object/class out of the results but I cannot for the life of me find the requirements to be able to put the results out of the variable list into an object in which the repeater can access **all** of the resultant columns and records.

#### Code Behind file

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Grab the CompanyID from the URL to parse into the query for company details page.
    int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CompanyID"], out int companyIDURL);

    // Create queries that grab the company details from the company directory. 
    using (BerkshireHathaway.Models.BerkshireHathawayEntitiesNew wde = 
        new BerkshireHathaway.Models.BerkshireHathawayEntitiesNew())
    {
        // Should look to bring in the company reports too.

        var reports = (from reportTable in wde.reports
                       join reportCategory in wde.report_category
                       on reportTable.report_categoryID 
                       equals reportCategory.report_categoryID
                       where reportTable.companyID == companyIDURL

                       // This needs to be directly typed. I've been putting 
                       // into the array.
                       select new 
                       { 
                           reportsID = reportTable.reportID, 
                           reportTypeDescription = reportCategory.description, 
                           sortOrder = reportCategory.sort_order 
                       }).ToList();

        ReportGrid.DataSource = reports;
        ReportGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

#### .ASPX

```html
<section id="Reports">
    <table>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ReportGrid" runat="server" 
                      ItemType="BerkshireHathaway.Models.report">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Item.report_category %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Item.report_title %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Item.report_date %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Item.summary %></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<%#Item.file_location %>" target="_blank">
                            Read Report.
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
</selection>
```

#### Debug of Object (Looks correct except for "Anonymous" type

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYouC.jpg)

#### Error Message Being Raised

#### Error Message Regarding Anonymous Type

Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType3`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'BerkshireHathaway.Models.report'.

Thanks for your assistance. I've spent hours trying to find the answer - my apologies if this is a common question.

Comment: You should create a new BerkshireHathaway.Models.report instead of using an anonymous type

Answer (score 1):

You have the `ItemType` of the Repeater specified as `BerkshireHathaway.Models.report` but when you perform the select you don't specify the type of the object which is why it becomes anonymous.

Instead you could do this:

```
select new report { reportsID = reportTable.reportID, reportTypeDescription = reportCategory.description, sortOrder = reportCategory.sort_order})
```

where "report" in `new report` should be `BerkshireHathaway.Models.report`. In other words the same type that's specified as the `ItemType` of the Repeater.

**Side note**

Your naming is way off btw, in C# we use `PascalCase` for class and property names NOT `camelCase` or `snake_case`.

Just an FYI.